# Possible to create login system in app

Tags: smartface.io

I was wondering if it was possible to add a login system to my app so that you have to login in order to view the rest of the content.

I've tried making two fields for username and password and tried to use the Instagram API however it wasn't successful.

Thanks

Comment: yes it is possible you can use webservice for login but I have not tried with Instagram API.

Comment: How do you use the webservice for login?

Comment: webservice is created by a back-end expert and we have to take that webservice in he application and give the input parameters.

Comment: do look into the following link
https://www.smartface.io/developer/guides/data-network/soap-services/

Comment: What would be the WSDL for a login system

Comment: http://restoreserver.devsoft.local:913/Service1.svc?wsdl this is the wsdl I am using for my application

Comment: This is what happens when I use this WSDL

Comment: I can't see your web-service image.

Comment: It's the link to the image

Comment: I know that but i can't see the image. Will you upload it to google drive and give me the link to download?

Comment: https://docs.google.com/drawings/d/1ycUci9bCDocL5FTILaOA25SEL33-14xXHltm7jTo20A/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Here is the link ↑

Comment: the above link which i provided won't work on your PC because it's my server url. You have to create a webservice and use it.

Comment: How do you create a web service?

Comment: it's a job of a backend specialist you can also search on google for how too create a webservice for login screen you will find many options